# How to remove the functionality of printing in the file viewer.js on Prebuilt Pdfjs from mozilla?

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

How to remove the functionality of printing in the file viewer.js on [Prebuilt Pdfjs](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download) from mozilla?

In this file, too much code(~10K) and I can not understand, how there it is implemented. Help please, at least explain how it is in this file is implemented. Advance thanks.

Comment: It is too lengthy to explain. But I've shown you the way to disable them without causing any crash/error. Hope that helps. If you are not sure about something, ask me on the comment section. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since, **removing or commenting out the HTML element throws error**, remove or comment the following lines from `viewer.js` to **remove Print, Download, Open** features (you can also remove any one of these since you only need to remove print):

```
eventBus.on('beforeprint', _boundEvents.beforePrint);
eventBus.on('afterprint', _boundEvents.afterPrint);
eventBus.on('openfile', webViewerOpenFile);
eventBus.on('print', webViewerPrint);
eventBus.on('download', webViewerDownload);
```

And as a precuation I would suggest disabling the **document property request** by disabling the concerned event too, so remove or comment

```
eventBus.on('documentproperties', webViewerDocumentProperties);
```

For being on the safe side, also remove or comment the `eventBus.off` for each of the events above. For example:

```
eventBus.off('print', webViewerPrint);
```

I couldn't tell you the line numbers of these codes exactly since my **viewer.js** has been modified beyond restoration to it's original form.

Finally, **add hidden attribute to the HTML elements** or figure out some other way to hide it, but whatever you do, **do not remove or comment the HTML elements**.